# Make the "close" link on bountied questions reject immediately

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, bounties

For bountied questions, make clicking "close" immediately pop up the error message `This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed`, instead of waiting until the end if the close vote input sequence (which can be quite long)

I have read the "duplicate" questions, but nine seem to directly ask for this change.

Some close options take a while (PK, maybe only a minute, but still) to complete, especially the "Other" option where the closer must type a message (maybe with links etc, so when done well it might not be that quick). Having the error show immediately would save the closer the time and trouble that is currently fruitless.

Comment: I think the problem is the will request in 2 queries to check if the post is bountied.  It is probably a minor query so might not impact performance, but the system will need to check before your vote because official to avoid the edge case of the bounty getting added while you were in the middle of closing.  So you are basically asking for it to check before and after you start to close, not just after.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Using the bounty status at page load would be plenty sufficient for the first check. It should be possible to determine this client side without requiring another AJAX call.

Comment: @Martin that's a good point, didn't think of checking for the bounty client side

Comment: It shouldn't need any call on the client side, or any extra effort/query anywhere, because the question has already been rendered as a bounty question, so the client "knows" it's a bounty question, so you have all the info you need to know know whether or not close should be short circuited.